# Harmonic points and equal angles

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ with incenter $I$. Two points $D$, $E$ lie on the line $BC$ such that $(E,D;B,C)=-1$. Let  $F$ be the projection of $D$ onto $IE$. Prove that $\angle AFI=\angle IDC$.

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem [+1]. It is almost immediate that FD is the polar line of E with respect to the incircle of ABC. But after ?